# jquery, how to select none?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a site with icons. Every icon is clickable.

If you click on icon, it gets selected (with border).

How can I define None to select? that is , to select no icon I want to click on empty spot..

Think about windows desktop, you can click on icon and it selected, and if you click on the backgroung all selection are gone..

I tried to select the body `$('body')` but it overwrites the div click function and cancel it..

Does someone have an idea?

Thanks

Comment: What does your "div click function" look like?  Can you define it there?

Comment: Yes:
  $('#MainFrame').click( function() {
    if (SelectedElem != "" ) { 
      SelectedElem.border('0px white 0');
      SelectedElem = "";
  });

Comment: How can I put code section in the forum? look how my post messed up with the code :) sorry...

Answer (score 3):

Edited below code after re-reading how you want it:

---

Something like this should work:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<style>
#main { width: 130px; background:red; margin:20px;  }
        #main .icon { padding:10px; float:left; width:40px; }          
</style>
<div id="main">
        <div class="icon"><img src="/icons/accept.png"></div>
        <div class="icon"><img src="/icons/add.png"></div>
        <div class="icon"><img src="/icons/anchor.png"></div>
        <div class="icon"><img src="/icons/application_add.png"></div>
        <div class="icon"><img src="/icons/application_edit.png"></div>

    </div>

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script language="javascript">
        $('#main .icon img').click(function() {
            $(this).parent().css('background', '#ccc'); 
            return false;
        });
        $('#main').click(function() { 
            $('#main .icon').each(function() {
                $(this).css('background', '#fff');
            });

            return false;
        });

        </script>
```

Comment: Hi, It isnt working because i have under the main div some divs with another id and class.. <BR> do you have anothe idea how can I select the main body?

Comment: @gabi: Can you provide some sample code?  I don't see where the problem would be

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you're after, define a click handler on the body that all clicks will bubble up to.

```
$('body').click(function(e) {
   if ($(e.target).hasClass('icon')) {
      //select icon
   }
   else {
      //clear selection
   }
});
```

Comment: @gabi, how does that pose a problem?

Answer (score 0):

In-case someone gets here by the question title... And you just  want an empty jQuery object, this is what you want:

```
$()
```

pre jQuery 1.4 this works best:

```
$([])
```

[Empty Selector In Jquery](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2008/Oct/03/No-Empty-Selector-in-jQuery)